HUION HS611 not working
So, I installed the official huion tablet drivers from the webiste https://www.huion.com/download/
it didn't work the tablet does nothing, it shows in the app but it does nothing, when i just plug and play the tablet kinda works (the cursor just hovers and i cant click anything)
i tried open tablet drivers, same thing.
when the apps can't detect the tablet it works, when the tablet shows in the app nothing happens
i love linux so far dispite of the problems (their seems to be a lot of 'em)
it would be helpful if anyone can help.
thx
i even removed wacom drivers using help from
Remove wacom from my system
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/xc8fdp/how_do_i_remove_the_preeinstalled_wacom_drivers/

Why are you asking here?

This is a Ubuntu Q&A Support site; and you don't even mention Ubuntu. Linux is supported on SE Unix & Linux.  The starting point for support is knowing what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're using, you've not told us that; with driver issues as some Ubuntu releases have kernel stack choice; switching stacks can be an easy fix (switching kernel also changes kernel modules commonly called 'drivers'), but we don't know what options you have available as you've not said what you're using.
